# Fool SAML authentication

Tags: windows, saml

My company's has given a corporate membership to Udemy, which is accessible from company's laptop only.

I tried to look into it and it uses SAML. If I open my company's Udemy website on any other laptop, it redirects to an IDP server (https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/sso/sp/initsso) of my company which fails.

Can I open the Udemy site on my company's laptop, and get the SAML token/key; Take it to some other system and access the website on other laptop as well?

Answer (score 3):

In the company I work for, we use SAML 2.0 authentication across all systems. If an employee is using the company's laptop, a client certificate is used for single sign-on with SAML 2.0.

However we still provide the fallback option to the user that if no certificate is sent in the SAML 2.0 authentication request, the corporate username and password can be used to authenticate in the Identity Provider.

SAML 2.0 support many single sign-on technologies to be used with it, some may be available only within your company's laptop (like a Kerberos token or client certificate). The SAML 2.0 authentication request cannot be modified during runtime since it will be created by the Service Provider or Identity Provider.

You can check with your company if providing the corporate user and password is supported.